# set -n not working in shell script when executing with source

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, source

this is the shell script..

```
#!/bin/bash
set -n
<<COMMENT1
    tHIS IS A MULTILINE COMMENT MAN 

COMMENT1
<<COMMENT1
THII
COMMENT1
:
echo "this is ashok"
echo "${LOGNAME}"
```

when executing with the sh and `./` its executing fine. but when I executed with source.

```
ashokkrishna@09:45:56:~/Desktop$ sh hello.sh
ashokkrishna@09:46:02:~/Desktop$ ./hello.sh
ashokkrishna@09:46:23:~/Desktop$ . hello.sh
this is ashok
ashokkrishna
```

why the output is coming for the script when I executed with source(.) command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [the docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Interactive-Shell-Behavior.html) on the behaviour of an *interactive* shell:

> 12. The `-n` invocation option is ignored, and ‘`set -n`’ has no effect (see [The Set Builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin)).

Since you sourced the script from an interactive shell, `set -n` is ignored.

Comment: could you please tell me the source code location of the source command.

Comment: why they ignored -n option in interactive shell?

Comment: @ashok what? O.o `source` is a builtin, its code is inside the bash source code: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/source.def Why shouldn't they ignore it? `-n` doesn't make any sense in an interactive shell.

Comment: actually I am a begginer so that I asked for the source code & why perticularly -n option disabled in interactive shells? this is my curiosity.

Comment: @ashok do you realise what `-n` does? Now tell why anybody using an interactive shell would use `-n` for a practical purpose.

Comment: I don't know about it.